# Selecting global or object print function

Tags: swift, cocoa, swift2

I am working with on a Cocoa project in Swift and confronted the following problem:

Several classes in the Cocoa Framework (such as `NSWindow` or `NSView`) implements a function called `print:` that opens a window in order to print something (don't really know what), so when I work within a class inherited from one of these classes, and want to log something to the console for debug purposes, I use the `print:` function. But the compiler thinks that I am referring to `self.print:` although I am referring to the global print function.

I found a workaround by declaring a global function like so:

```
func myPrint(o : Any?)
{
     print(o)
}
```

and use `myPrint:` instead of `print:` in cases where the compiler will confuse which function I am referring to. I am pretty sure that there probably are other functions in this case other then `print:`. Is my workaround or overriding the inherited `print:` function the only solution or can I give the compiler somehow a hint saying that I want to refer to the global `print:` function?

PS: I am using Swift 2.0 so `println:` is not available.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Indeed, `NSView` has a

```
func print(_ sender: AnyObject?)
```

method to open the Print panel, which is an unfortunate conincidence.

Your `myPrint()` wrapper has some limitations, for example

```
myPrint("b", appendNewline : false)
```

does not compile. A better implementation would be

```
func myPrint<T>(o : T, appendNewline nl: Bool = true) {
    print(o, appendNewline: nl)
}
```

**But** you can simply prepend the module name "Swift" to refer to the global function explicitly:

```
Swift.print("xxx")
```

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is simply to write output to the console, I would use the alternate global function `debugPrint(_:)` for that purpose here.

Comment: A beautiful workaround. I'm interested why do you qualify your answer with "If your goal is simply to write output to the console"? Surely this is the main use-case for `print` anyway?

Comment: primarily for semantics  :)  and because, as mentioned by OP, some classes in AppKit appear to overload `print(_:)` for their own purpose

Comment: It also adds a newline whereas print doesn't unless explicitly specified.