# Calling `print` inside NSView opens print dialog

Tags: macos, swift, swift2

This is bizarre. I have a simple storyboard placeholder with `GridView` for the class name attribute.

```
class GridView: NSView {

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        print("coder: \(coder)")
    }

    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        let rect = NSBezierPath(rect: dirtyRect)
        NSColor.redColor().setFill()
        rect.fill()
    }
}
```

This worked as expected with just `drawRect` implemented, but after I added the initialiser it started opening the print dialog every time I run the app.

[image: Print dialog]

Why does this happen and how can I properly reimplement the storyboard initialiser for a custom view?

Comment: have you tried removing the `print` statement? might be a very strange bug...

Comment: Oh wow! You're right, `print` is the reason it's doing that... This truly boggles the mind!

Comment: well, it should just not do that, print is supposed to do something quite different... :D

Comment: Related: [Selecting global or object function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30955889/selecting-global-or-object-function).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Calling `print()` does something different as it should - more precisely: something different as you would expect. It calls [`NSView`'s `print(sender: AnyObject?)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/print:) instead of the logging print. You could consider this as a bug or at least as quite unexpected behavior since the `Swift.print(...)` is generally much more used.

> This action method opens the Print panel, and if the user chooses an option other than canceling, prints the receiver and all its subviews to the device specified in the Print panel.

Take a look at [this post in the apple dev forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/5233).

In fact it is not a bug since calling the `print` which is "closer" in the current context is certainly the correct way. Calling the parent's `print` is a lot more reasonable than calling some arbitrary other `print`. Only the fact that you normally use the *other* print is the confusing point here since in general you do not worry in what scope the logging `print` is located - it just works. If you think the other way around and would want to use the printing `print` of your parent it would be a ***lot*** more confusing having to explicitly state that you want to use the parents `print` and not the `Swift.print(...)`.

The only *"solution"* would be to use different names for the two functions which is probably not going to happen.

Comment: Funny thing is, in the thread over at page you linked, people consider this as `certainly not a bug.` :)

Comment: @MorganWilde yeah, that´s why expanded my answer - i might want to remove the "bug" word, because it is just strange but somewhat reasonable to behave that way.

Comment: This is a bug. The debug `print` is much more heavily used than `print` the Cocoa printing method, so the framework should do something about that. It's just bad design.

Comment: @MorganWilde kind of, but just from a compiler perspective it is not really a bug because calling the print of the object you are currently in is actually the more correct way instead of calling some random static print that is defined somewhere else.

Comment: sure, it's not the compiler that's at fault here, it's the print method on these Cocoa classes that needs changing. IMHO

Comment: @MorganWilde maybe, yes. But it will quite difficult to change the name or parameters of some functions that are heavily in use already. I think it might be to late for that :/

Comment: Swift2 just came out, so it's sure not too late. The only reason it's confusing those methods is that Cocoa has AnyObject? in the signature. By changing that to something more reasonable it could spare us from this stupid need to namespacing an otherwise global function.

Comment: @MorganWilde you will not get around that issue, the NSView.print should just be able to print anything, as well as the Swift.print should be able to print anything. The only viable option would to be to rename one of them. I doubt that will happen - even if I think it might be a good idea.

Comment: This is a bug or at least a stupid design decision by Apple. Sometimes print calls the print dialog and sometimes it calls println. What on earth was wrong with println anyway?

Answer (score 2):

The reason it's calling the print dialog is that Swift 2 apparently has two methods with the same signature.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty old thread, but I must add here that you can write:

```
Swift.print("something")
```

and you would be using the "log print" function instead of view's one.