# Unintended print dialog after viewDidLoad()

Tags: xcode, macos, swift

As the title says I have a problem where a print dialog pops up (as if I had pressed ⌘P). But I never call any function in code which would lead to this behavior.

Are there any configurations where I can turn it on/off or a link in the Storyboard file (for OS X 10.10) which I could have accidentally set ?

There is some assembly code which shows when the print command is executed:

```
    0x7fff917c4acb <+554>:  xorl   %r12d, %r12d
    0x7fff917c4ace <+557>:  movq   $-0x1, %rdx
    0x7fff917c4ad5 <+564>:  movl   $0x1, %r9d
    0x7fff917c4adb <+570>:  movq   -0x30(%rbp), %rdi
    0x7fff917c4adf <+574>:  movq   -0x13d1b42e(%rip), %rsi   ; "nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:"
    0x7fff917c4ae6 <+581>:  movq   %rax, %rcx
    0x7fff917c4ae9 <+584>:  movq   -0x50(%rbp), %r8
->  0x7fff917c4aed <+588>:  callq  *-0x13f3fcdb(%rip)        ; (void *)0x00007fff92ff30c0: objc_msgSend
    0x7fff917c4af3 <+594>:  movq   %r14, %r13
    0x7fff917c4af6 <+597>:  xorl   %r12d, %r12d
    0x7fff917c4af9 <+600>:  callq  0x7fff920e2dfa
```

I've also searched my project for print commands and settings but I couldn't find any reference to what has happened.

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30955889/selecting-global-or-object-function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Swift 1.2 using `print()` instead of `println()` can cause this problem.
Make sure to use only the latter syntax