# Swift 2.0: `print` function generates "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments" error

Tags: ios, swift

The `print` function in a class is mysteriously generating the following error: `Argument passed to call that takes no arguments`.

However, the error goes away if we use `Swift.print` instead of just `print` to invoke the function.

We are using Swift 2 and Xcode 7.

Why does this happen?

Test function below where the error gets generated:

```
func test() {
    print("why does this fail")
}
```

Comment: Is that in a NSView or NSWindow subclass? Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30955889/selecting-global-or-object-print-function.

Comment: That code works for me.  Can you show the rest of your class.  Have you defined a function called `print` ? You have tagged this `iOS` but are you actually running on OS X?

Comment: Yes, it's for iOS @Paulw11. Will post cleaned up version of class shortly.

Comment: @MartinR it's a subclass of `NSObject` and `NSCoding`

Comment: Does `print()` without arguments compile? If yes, command-click on "print" to jump to the definition. What do you get?

Comment: @MartinR OK boneheaded question. There was a `print` function already defined in the class. Feeling quite stupid now. :)

Comment: @MartinR want to post as an answer so you can get credit?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> However, the error goes away if we use `Swift.print` instead of just `print` to invoke the function.

That means that there is a `print()` method defined in your class
or in one of its superclasses, so that `print()` is resolved as 
the method call `self.print()`.

By prefixing the module name "Swift" you refer to the global `print()`
function instead.

Comment: thanks again. it was such a boneheaded question, but this is the danger of coding on little sleep. :) hope it helps some other sleep-deprived person in the future!