# Drawing at Cocoa with Swift Creates an error

Tags: swift, cocoa

When trying to draw just like in an iOS application we faced a problem. After hours of search with no luck, we decided to ask here.

To make a drawing we created a class as

```
import Cocoa

class DrawImageHolder: NSView {
  override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.drawRect(dirtyRect)
       print(" drawRect is executed  ")

       // drawing code 
  }
}
```

then we connected the class to a `NSView` like this

[image]

But we have received

> -[NSApplication runModalForWindow:] may not be invoked inside of transaction commit (usually this means it was invoked inside of a
>   view's -drawRect: method.) The modal dialog has been suppressed to
>   avoid deadlock.

message from console instead of drawing.

Besides the  print(" drawRect is executed  ") was not executed.

Most probably we are forgetting something simple.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30955889/selecting-global-or-object-print-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class inherits from NSView:

```
class DrawImageHolder: NSView
```

So the `print` you're using:

```
print(" drawRect is executed  ")
```

is actually `NSView`'s `print`. The view tries to show a dialog for printing, and as the error states, it does from a place it shouldn't.

The solution is to prefix `print` with `Swift` so that you're explicitly using Swift's `print` instead of `NSView`'s `print`:

```
class DrawImageHolder: NSView {
  override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
       super.drawRect(dirtyRect)
       Swift.print(" drawRect is executed  ")
  }
}
```

Comment: `CGContextFillPath(context)` should not be there for drawing code in comments so when it is erased problem has been solved.