# Swift.print() vs print()

Tags: swift, xcode, printing

I have found that since Xcode will no longer digest println() I am
    left with either Swift.print() or print()   .   My question is, 
    what is the difference between the two? I have not been able to 
    find a conclusive answer online or in the 
    Swift Prog. Lang. (Swift 3.0.1) from apple.

```
What prompted me to ask was that I noticed in the playground that
in the review area on the right Swift.print() showed no digested
data when passing a var whereas print() showed "example\n".
```

Thank You.

Comment: This is the same command. `print` is the function, `Swift` is the module name. `Swift.print` is just disambiguation for `print`, by adding the module name in front of the function name. // And by the way `println` has been removed a long time ago already. ;)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37249468/2227743 (and I believe this has changed in Swift 4, btw, no need for the disambiguation anymore)

Comment: Thank you, I'm new to swift. That makes total sense! And thank you for clarifying on println() - the book I was using was from 2015 so I got a current one.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if println was good at that. but Swift.print
is pretty good at hanging runtime

If the outgoing println was not good at hanging the simuator here's 
your difference right there.